# Objective C - Decrypt File Encrypted With AESCrypt (www.aescrypt.com)

Tags: java, objective-c, encryption, methods

I need to rewrite a Java method which does decryption of an encrypted file, which is encrypted with the AESCrypt (http://www.aescrypt.com). This program uses a custom file format (.aes) and needs to be handled in a custom way. There is already a Java method like I said. So far I completed rewriting a portion of the method, and so far it works. But I am stuck at some point. I could not find the equivalent of `IvParameterSpec` and `SecretKeySpec`.

Please see the Java method and the portion that I have completed. It would be great if you guys can give me a pointer how to continue with the method.

PS. Do not worry about the parameters as Java uses an InputStream and an OutputStream, I use a NSFileHandle and an NSOutputStream.

Thanks.

```
public void decrypt(long inSize, InputStream in, OutputStream out)
throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    try {
        byte[] text = null, backup = null;
        long total = 3 + 1 + 1 + BLOCK_SIZE + BLOCK_SIZE + KEY_SIZE + SHA_SIZE + 1 + SHA_SIZE;
        int version;

        text = new byte[3];
        readBytes(in, text);    // Heading.
        if (!new String(text, "UTF-8").equals("AES")) {
            throw new IOException("Invalid file header");
        }

        version = in.read();    // Version.
        if (version < 1 || version > 2) {
            throw new IOException("Unsupported version number: " + version);
        }
        debug("Version: " + version);

        in.read();  // Reserved.

        if (version == 2) { // Extensions.
            text = new byte[2];
            int len;
            do {
                readBytes(in, text);
                len = ((0xff & (int) text[0]) << 8) | (0xff & (int) text[1]);
                if (in.skip(len) != len) {
                    throw new IOException("Unexpected end of extension");
                }
                total += 2 + len;
                debug("Skipped extension sized: " + len);
            } while (len != 0);
        }

        text = new byte[BLOCK_SIZE];
        readBytes(in, text);    // Initialization Vector.
        ivSpec1 = new IvParameterSpec(text);
        aesKey1 = new SecretKeySpec(generateAESKey1(ivSpec1.getIV(), password), CRYPT_ALG);
        debug("IV1: ", ivSpec1.getIV());
        debug("AES1: ", aesKey1.getEncoded());

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKey1, ivSpec1);
        backup = new byte[BLOCK_SIZE + KEY_SIZE];
        readBytes(in, backup);  // IV and key to decrypt file contents.
        debug("IV2 + AES2 ciphertext: ", backup);
        text = cipher.doFinal(backup);
        ivSpec2 = new IvParameterSpec(text, 0, BLOCK_SIZE);
        aesKey2 = new SecretKeySpec(text, BLOCK_SIZE, KEY_SIZE, CRYPT_ALG);
        debug("IV2: ", ivSpec2.getIV());
        debug("AES2: ", aesKey2.getEncoded());

        hmac.init(new SecretKeySpec(aesKey1.getEncoded(), HMAC_ALG));
        backup = hmac.doFinal(backup);
        text = new byte[SHA_SIZE];
        readBytes(in, text);    // HMAC and authenticity test.
        if (!Arrays.equals(backup, text)) {
            throw new IOException("Message has been altered or password incorrect");
        }
        debug("HMAC1: ", text);

        total = inSize - total; // Payload size.
        if (total % BLOCK_SIZE != 0) {
            throw new IOException("Input file is corrupt");
        }
        if (total == 0) {   // Hack: empty files won't enter block-processing for-loop below. 
            in.read();  // Skip last block size mod 16.
        }
        debug("Payload size: " + total);

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKey2, ivSpec2);
        hmac.init(new SecretKeySpec(aesKey2.getEncoded(), HMAC_ALG));
        backup = new byte[BLOCK_SIZE];
        text = new byte[BLOCK_SIZE];
        for (int block = (int) (total / BLOCK_SIZE); block > 0; block--) {
            int len = BLOCK_SIZE;
            if (in.read(backup, 0, len) != len) {   // Cyphertext block.
                throw new IOException("Unexpected end of file contents");
            }
            cipher.update(backup, 0, len, text);
            hmac.update(backup, 0, len);
            if (block == 1) {
                int last = in.read();   // Last block size mod 16.
                debug("Last block size mod 16: " + last);
                len = (last > 0 ? last : BLOCK_SIZE);
            }
            out.write(text, 0, len);
        }
        out.write(cipher.doFinal());

        backup = hmac.doFinal();
        text = new byte[SHA_SIZE];
        readBytes(in, text);    // HMAC and authenticity test.
        if (!Arrays.equals(backup, text)) {
            throw new IOException("Message has been altered or password incorrect");
        }
        debug("HMAC2: ", text);
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        throw new GeneralSecurityException(JCE_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE, e);
    }
}
```

And the ObjC Method so far:

```
- (void)decrypt:(unsigned long long)filesize in:(NSFileHandle *)in out:(NSOutputStream *)out {
long total = 3 + 1 + 1 + BLOCK_SIZE + BLOCK_SIZE + KEY_SIZE + SHA_SIZE + 1 + SHA_SIZE;
int version;

int byteCounter = 0;

NSData *buffer = nil;
buffer = [in readDataOfLength:total];

NSData *headerData = [self getSubDataFrom:byteCounter To:3 withData:buffer];
byteCounter += 3;

NSString *text  = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:headerData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"header: %@", text);

if(![text isEqualToString:@"AES"]) {
    NSLog(@"Invalid file header!");
    return;
}

NSData *verData = [self getSubDataFrom:byteCounter To:1 withData:buffer];
version = [[self returnHexRepForData:verData] intValue];
byteCounter += 1;
NSLog(@"version: %d", version);

if(version < 1 || version > 2) {
    NSLog(@"Unsupported version number: %d", version);
    return;
}

if(version == 2) {
    int len = 0;

    do {
        NSData *ext1 = [self getSubDataFrom:byteCounter To:1 withData:buffer];
        int ext1byte = [[self returnHexRepForData:ext1] intValue];
        byteCounter++;

        NSData *ext2 = [self getSubDataFrom:byteCounter To:1 withData:buffer];
        int ext2byte = [[self returnHexRepForData:ext2] intValue];
        byteCounter++;

        len = ((0xff & (int) ext1byte) << 8) | (0xff & (int) ext2byte);

        total += 2 + len;

        NSLog(@"Skipped extension sized: %d",len);

    } while (len != 0);
}

uint8_t iv[BLOCK_SIZE];
memset((void *) iv, 0x0, (size_t) sizeof(iv));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved the goal by porting C (Linux) source code into iOS...

Answer (score 0):

Attack the problem in parts, the java method is doing several things in one function.

1. Read the file. Get the encryption key and iv.
2. Determine the padding (if any).
3. Decrypt with CCCrypt.

Do all these things in separate methods with on overall method calling them. The result of CCCrypt will match the Java implementation if you supply all the same inputs.